# Replace the first number of each group/factor with new value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace the first values of each `IndID` with new values from a separate `data.frame`. Note, there are a differing number of observations for each `IndID`.

Using the example code below, I want to replace the first values of `number1` and `number2` with the corresponding column names in the `dat2` `df`. In some instances, the replacement value is `NA`.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(IndID = rep(c("A","A","B","c","c","D"), each  = 5),
                  number1 = sample(1:100,30),
                  number2 = sample(1:100,30))

dat2 <- data.frame(IndID = c("A","B","c","D"),
                  number1 = c(555,666,NA,888),
                  number2 = c(111,222,NA,444))
```

The preferred result would produce the following with a much more effective and elegant approach. I suspect `dplyr` is an appropriate tool, but always enjoy learning other methods.

```
dat[1,2:3] <- c(555,111)
dat[11,2:3] <- c(666,222)
dat[16,2:3] <- c(NA,NA)
dat[26,2:3] <- c(888,444)
dat
```

Comment: Wow. Much appreciated. I was certainly off on the route I was headed down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
 dat[match(dat2$IndID, dat$IndID),] <- dat2
```

Answer (score 4):

With data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(dat)
DT[dat2, on=.(IndID), mult="first", `:=`(number1 = i.number1, number2 = i.number2)]
```

You could alternately use `setDT(dat)` instead of creating `DT`.

By the way, this throws a warning since the OP mixed floats (in dat2) with ints (in dat). Unlike base R, data.table guards against accidental coercion when modifying columns.

---

If you want to avoid manually specifying the columns (like in @Jay's answer):

```
cols = setdiff(names(dat2), "IndID")
DT[dat2, on=.(IndID), mult="first", (cols) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", cols))]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using a base R approach, you can do the following. You get indices of the first row for each `IndID`, which is `ind`. Then, you know which rows you need to replace numbers in `number1` and `number2`. Use the indices and replace numbers with `dat2`.

```
ind <- which(!duplicated(dat$IndID))
dat[ind, 2] <- dat2$number1
dat[ind, 3] <- dat2$number2


#   IndID number1 number2
#1      A     555     111
#2      A      37      60
#3      A      57     100
#4      A      89      19
#5      A      20      80
#6      A      86      64
#7      A      97      75
#8      A      62      11
#9      A      58      67
#10     A       6      38
#11     B     666     222
#12     B      16      58
#13     B      61      69
#14     B      34      98
#15     B      67      46
#16     c      NA      NA
#17     c      88       2
#18     c      83      40
#19     c      32      61
#20     c      63      57
#21     c      75      39
#22     c      17      88
#23     c      51      35
#24     c      10      97
#25     c      21       6
#26     D     888     444
#27     D       1      24
#28     D      28      91
#29     D      81      48
#30     D      25      29
```

Comment: I think `match` (in Jay's answer) is preferable, since it handles cases where IndID entries in dat2 are (i) in a different order than in dat and (ii) are missing in dat.

Comment: @Frank I agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 <- lapply(split(dat, dat$IndID), function( x ) {  # split dat by IndID column
  x[1, ] <- dat2[dat2$IndID %in% unique(x$IndID), ]  # replace first row with the matching row of dat2
  return( x )                                        # return modified data  
  })

do.call( 'rbind', a1)  # combine all list elements together using rbind

#      IndID number1 number2
# A.1      A     555     111
# A.2      A      37      60
# A.3      A      57     100
# A.4      A      89      19
# A.5      A      20      80
# A.6      A      86      64
# A.7      A      97      75
# A.8      A      62      11
# A.9      A      58      67
# A.10     A       6      38
# B.11     B     666     222
# B.12     B      16      58
# B.13     B      61      69
# B.14     B      34      98
# B.15     B      67      46
# c.16     c      NA      NA
# c.17     c      88       2
# c.18     c      83      40
# c.19     c      32      61
# c.20     c      63      57
# c.21     c      75      39
# c.22     c      17      88
# c.23     c      51      35
# c.24     c      10      97
# c.25     c      21       6
# D.26     D     888     444
# D.27     D       1      24
# D.28     D      28      91
# D.29     D      81      48
# D.30     D      25      29
```